# How to manage download/upload like Filesharing sites does?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, download

**My Goal**

Recently, my interest went to file download/upload. What I want to achieve is to make a "system" to download/upload files on the server. I want to be able to tranfer large files and resume the download after. All of this has to be done async (if possible). I don't want to build a filesharing site, I only do this for learning.

**What I need to know**

I want know what are my options to achieve it professionaly. I red alot of topic on here where  people talk about using some jquery-plugin or else, but I want to do it myself. I know it would be easier and probably(surely) better than mine, but I will not help me understand the concept behing. Others talked about using an IFRAME and the attribute TARGET, but it seems not a really "clean" solution since, the TARGET attribute is not accepted in XHTML Strict.

Id like to know what should I be looking for, since I don't even know what to search. I'm not looking for a complete solution, but if you got a nice tutorial that shows some of the concept I would appreciate it.

I've red about using Range to resume download, but the tutorials (or articles) I've found doesn't really explain the concept and I'm a little confuse about how it works and how PHP handle it.

**Good to know**

1. My site is developed in PHP and I am using JQuery as Javascript's
   lib (but would not mind to use "pure" Javascript solution if JQuery
   is limiting possibilities somehow).
2. I don't want to use a lib or JQuery plugin like JQuery File Upload.

Comment: This may be useful for a nice upload progress bar - http://www.haughin.com/2007/10/php-upload-progress-with-php-52-apc/

Comment: Sorry, I can't answer that, this is not a real question.

Comment: I dont think u get the point of this site! Try google...

Comment: The IFRAME solution might not work in xhtml strict but why anyone would author in XHTML at this point is beyond me (xhtml != html, and html 5 is a newer standard).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Adoption and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML#Criticism.

Comment: @iblue I don't want to be rude, but the part where I ask "What are the solutions" consists of a question. There might be no "code", but this question seems to interest a lot of people. Other posts haven't answer the questions I'm asking (at least didn't found one) and I think I'm not the only one who would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only way to get advanced file transfer capabilities, especially in a cross-browser way, is to use a plugin, like Flash or Java and build a client. HTML and Javascript simply do not provide the power needed to do things like upload an entire directory or control the upload rate or do client-side processing in a substantial way.